# How to make embed code using jquery and html?

Tags: jquery, html, thickbox

I like to create an link image and i need to popup my feedback window once user clciks that image icon in his website. how can i deliver image link icon through embed code(Functionality is once image icon clicked popup window opens with my feedback page)

Now i am using(Sample codes)...

```
<div>
<link href="thickbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="thickbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<a id="feedback" onclick="tb_show('Feedback', 'http://myfeedbackpage.com/&keepThis=true&TB_iframe=1&width=1000&height=400&model=true');" href="javascript: void(0);"><img src="feedback.jpg" width="29" height="31" alt="feedback" style="vertical-align:bottom" /></a>
</div>
```

I am using thick box for popup. **Help me how to simplify these codes as embed codes**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're asking how to move your `onclick` property into a separate file. First, change the HTML to just:

```
<a id="feedback" href="#"><img src="feedback.jpg" width="29" height="31" alt="feedback" style="vertical-align:bottom" /></a>
```

Then in your JavaScript file write:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#feedback").click(function() {
        tb_show('Feedback', 'http://myfeedbackpage.com/&keepThis=true&TB_iframe=1&width=1000&height=400&model=true');
    });
});
```

Comment: i know this. i need to embed these codes and want to give to client as embed code with minimum lines

Comment: The absolute minimum would be to "minify" jQuery, Thickbox, and your code into a single `.js` file. Then the only code required would be (1) an ID or class attribute on the `<a>` tag, (2) a `<link>` tag for the stylesheet, and (3) a `<script>` tag